# Android : Is it necessary to include Google Play services to use GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have a library android project with size 200kb. Now I want to use GCM in it. To use GCM I have to include Google Play Services, which increases my project size by 1 MB making it to 1.2 MB which is kind of bad. Any work around for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no workaround

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

You need google play services

Comment: Google Play services is almost 5 times of my project size. Can't we somehow include some part of Google Play services, only that which is used by GCM ?

Comment: i suggest you enable proguard. this will obfuscate remove unwanted code. But i don't think there is any other workaround as far as i know. the increase is also not more. should not worry too much

Comment: For short term fix, you could use the old deprecated GCM classes  based around http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html which do not require Play Services. There's no telling when these classes will stop being supported though

Answer (score 4):

From the Google Play services version 6.5, you can selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app.

To include GCM part only, use:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use google play service library either if it increase the size of your apk.
Please visit this link

[Google Cloud Messaging for Android library vs. Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473803/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-library-vs-google-play-services)

Answer (score -1):

Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.

It will save you memory in project.

Comment: This doesn't matter to your APK size.  As always the APK is compiled against a stub implementation with linking against the actual library on the device (either already there, or downloadable).